# Muitliple Node.js servers using NGINX proxys

Tags: node.js, nginx

### The Goal:

Use muitiple live node.js servers independent of each other under different doc roots.

### Using NGINX

```
server {
    server_name .lolwut1.com;
    root /var/www/html/lolwut1;
    # proxy pass to nodejs
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:5001/;
    }
}

server {
    server_name .lolwut2.com;
    root /var/www/html/lolwut2;
    # proxy pass to nodejs
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:5002/;
    }
}
```

### /var/www/html/lolwut1/app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("lolwut1\n");
});
server.listen(5001);
```

### /var/www/html/lolwut2/app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("lolwut2\n");
});
server.listen(5002);
```

### So when I...

`node app.js` in `/var/www/html/lolwut1/app.js` and hit `lolwut1.com` I'm all good.

### Questions:

1. But now what If I want to start the second node server?
2. Is this a bad approach?... Am I thinking about this the wrong way?
3. [What are the advantages/disadvantages of using node.js with a `connect.vhost` directive as a router rather than NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994413/vhost-using-node-js-connect-vhost-directive-vs-nginx-proxy-pass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) to start and stop your node apps.
2. You're doing it right! This approach has worked well for me for quite a while.
3. **Connect vhost Advantage:** You don't have to install and configure nginx. The whole stack is node.js.

   **Nginx Advantage:** Nginx is a mature and stable web server. It's very unlikely to crash or exhibit strange behavior. It can also host your static site, PHP site, etc.

   If it were me, unless I needed some particular feature of Nginx, I'd pick Connect vhost or [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) for the sake of having an all-node.js stack.

Comment: ported too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994413/vhost-using-node-js-connect-vhost-directive-vs-nginx-proxy-pass

Answer (score 1):

> But now what If I want to start the second node server? Is this a bad approach?...

when you cd to `/var/www/html/lolwut2/` and run `node app.js`, this should start the second server on port 5002 and lolwut2.com should work.

> Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

That's a valid way to run multiple node apps on the same server if you have enough memory, and plenty of cpu power.  This is also a good way to scale a single node app on the same machine to take advantage of multiple cores by running multiple nodes and using the `upstream` directive (like here https://serverfault.com/questions/179247/can-nginx-round-robin-to-a-server-list-on-different-ports)

Comment: ported too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994413/vhost-using-node-js-connect-vhost-directive-vs-nginx-proxy-pass

Comment: answered there to question #3